# How can I get the "actual" count of element in a IEnumerable?

Tags: linq, ienumerable

If I wrote :

```
for (int i = 0; i < Strutture.Count(); i++)
{
}
```

and Strutture is an IEnumerable with 200 elements, IIS crash. That's because I see every time I do `Strutture.Count()` it executes all LINQ queries linked with that IEnumerable.

So, how can I get the "current" number of elements? I need a list?

Comment: my be it's time to try `foreach`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"That's because I see every time I do Strutture.Count() it executes all LINQ queries linked with that IEnumerable."

Without doing such, how is it going to know how many elements there are?

For example:

```
Enumerable.Range(0,1000).Where(i => i % 2==0).Skip(100).Take(5).Count();
```

Without executing the LINQ, how could you know how many elements there are?

If you want to know how many elements there are in the source (e.g. Enumerable.Range) then I suggest you use a reference to that source and query it directly.  E.g.

```
 var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0,1000);
 numbers.Count();
```

Also keep in mind some data sources don't really have a concept of 'Count' or if they do it involves going through every single item and counting them.

Lastly, if you're using .Count() repetitively [and you don't expect the value to actually change] it can be a good idea to cache:

```
 var count = numbers.Count();
 for (int i =0; i<count; i++) //  Do Something
```

Supplemental:

"At first Count(), LINQ queries are executes. Than, for the next, it just "check" the value :) Not "execute the LINQ query again..." :)" - **Markzzz**

Then why don't we do that?

```
var query = Enumerable.Range(0,1000).Where(i => i % 2==0).Skip(100).Take(5).Count();
var result = query.ToArray() //Gets and stores the result!
result.Length;
```

:)

"But when I do the first "count", it should store (after the LINQ queries) the new IEnumerable (the state is changed). If I do again .Count(), why LINQ need to execute again ALL queries." - **Markzzz**

Because you're creating a *query* that gets compiled down into X,Y,Z.  You're running the same query twice however the result may vary.

For example, check this out:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dataSource = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList();
        var query = dataSource.Where(i => i % 2 == 0);

        //Run the query once and return the count:
        Console.WriteLine(query.Count());  //50

        //Now lets modify the datasource - remembering this could be a table in a db etc.
        dataSource.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(100, 100));

        //Run the query again and return the count:
        Console.WriteLine(query.Count());  //100
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This is why I recommended storing the results of the query above!

Comment: "Without doing such, how is it going to know how many elements there are?" : with Logic, I thought this. At first Count(), LINQ queries are executes. Than, for the next, it just "check" the value :) Not "execute the LINQ query again..." :)

Comment: With logic?  Replace the '(i => i % 2==0)' with '(i => i == Random.Next())' and see how far your logic gets you :P  Given your comment, it sounds like you should cache the result of your query - I'll add an example.

Comment: But when I do the first "count", it should store (after the LINQ queries) the new IEnumerable (the state is changed). If I do again .Count(), why LINQ need to execute again ALL queries. It should execute the query between the first Count() and the second Count(), where the data should be changed. That's my logic :)

Comment: Yeah, in fact thinking about "updating" the database, this make sense :) Thank you for clarify it out!

Comment: P.S. The AddRange it is executed at the second Count() or immediatly?

Comment: The AddRange is a List function [not linq] and AFAIK happens immediately.

Comment: Well. So, just to know, how is the "function" that will "execute" all previously query on LINQ? I think there will be a list... (I mean, .Where won't, Count will).

Comment: I think you need to look in more depth at how Linq works - it's beyond the scope of this comment field.  I suspect you'll find that Where does in fact execute the entire chain of statements [again, it wouldn't make since if it didn't].

Comment: I don't think so! In fact, if I do .Where on IEnumerable, and I never cycle it (that call .Count()), it will never executed :O

Comment: Of course, because the 'where' just adds some logic to the query.  Count() executes the query and gets a result. Read up on the concepts of deffered processing and streaming.

Comment: "Count() executes the query and gets a result." Yeah, that was my question :) Other Count(), which other function executes queries? Just for knowledge :)

Comment: Also, if I do a .ToList() and than a .Count(), it will executes the query 2 times, right?

Comment: If a function returns an IEnumerable then you can probably assume that is returns a 'query' - if it returns data e.g. int Count or List<T> ToList() then it probably is executing the query and giving you a result.  If you do .ToList() and .Count() you are executing two queries - because both return 'data'. Of course, doing .Count() on a List is probably very fast.

Answer (score 2):

*Materialize* the number:

```
int number = Strutture.Count();
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
}
```

or *materialize* the list:

```
var list = Strutture.ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
}
```

or use a `foreach`

```
foreach(var item in Strutture)
{   
}
```